# Failed to find `/usr/bin/docker-quickstart` when running CDH5 Docker image

Tags: docker, cloudera

I've downloaded the [CDH 5.12 Quickstart Docker image](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-12.html) from Cloudera but it fails to run.

```
$ docker import cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.12.0-0-beta-docker.tar.gz
sha256:8fe04d8a55477d648e9e28d1517a21e22584fd912d06de84a912a6e2533a256c
$ docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i 8fe04d8a5547 /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/bin/docker-quickstart\": stat /usr/bin/docker-quickstart: no such file or directory".
```

On the other hand, doing `docker pull cloudera/quickstart:latest` gives me an image for which the above works - it's just an older one (5.07 I believe).

[This blog post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Hadoop-101-Training-Quickstart/Error-when-executing-the-command-docker-run/td-p/35429) suggests that something changed around CDH 5.10. How then am I supposed to run newer images?